# WCF net.tcp - Connection refused by target machine

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, net.tcp

I am having this issue over Windows 8 x 64 as well as Windows 7 x 64 OS. I have a simple WCF service which uses net.tcp binding.

I have followed many articles to write this simple service including this following on MSDN: [Hosting and Consuming WCF services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic4)

My service and config files are exactly as mentioned in above article.

After installing this WCF service using InstallUtil.exe as a windows 
service, I can see the service getting installed correctly and it 
runs without any error. I have tried to add traces on OnStart and 
OnStop methods of Windows service and found nothing wrong.
As soon as I try to reference this endpoint from another solution, I 
get following error.

> Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8523/Inbound. The connection 
>   attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:00.9531494. TCP error code 
>   10061: No connection could be made because the target machine 
>   actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8523.

I have tried most of the posts related to this issue over the internet and also I have tried opening firewalls, un-installing antivirus software, tried different ports, explicitly created inbound and outbound rules for these ports in firewall, etc. Still I am not able to access this Windows service which hosts my net.tcp based WCF service. My TCP port sharing service and TCP listner adaptor services are on and also I have turned on nescessary Windows features required to run these TCP services.

One thing I can see is that I can always access this service in the same solution in another project, because Visual Studio creates a Wcf Service Host (WcfSvcHost) immediately when I try to reference this service, which finds all endpoints in all project in current solution and loads them up. As long as this host is running, I can reference this service in another solution as well without issue.

The Windows service which hosts my service is also same as given code. Clearly this creates the instance of ServiceHost and runs it. I have verified this with some logs that it gets executed successfully when service starts. But I am not able to see this process running in Task Manager when my service starts. I could see this service when Visual Studio runs it while I am debugging in the same solution or trying to reference in same solution as I mentioned above.

Now my question is, am I supposed to see this WcfSvceHost service in Task Manager when my service starts? I believe I should. Please correct me if I 
am wrong.

Do I need to grant any special permissions to my Windows service to run this ServiceHost or is the issue completely different? Am I overlooking something very obvious here? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my config file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings />
<client />
<services>
  <service name="MyWcfServiceLibrary.WCFService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="TCPEndPoint" contract="MyWcfServiceLibrary.IWCFService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8523/MyWCFService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>        
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: The issue was a silly mistake here. My apologies. I was not able to post my service class code because stack overflow did not allow me. In myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWCFService)), I mistakenly referenced the windows service class instead of WCF service. That is the reason it was not creating WCF service host. Aria, I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's debug by elimination.
Did you enable port sharing?
This is for sharing TCP ports across multiple processes.According to Microsoft "this service is installed as part of WCF, but the service is not enabled by default as a security precaution".

Here is how to enable the Net.TCP Port Sharing Service using MMC

1. From the Start menu, open the Services Management Console either by opening a Command Prompt window and typing services.msc or by opening Run and typing services.msc into the Open box.
2. In the Name column of the list of services, right-click the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service, and select Properties from the menu.
3. To enable the manual start-up of the service, in the Properties window select the General tab, and in the Startup type box select Manual, and then click Apply.
4. To start the service, in the Service status area, click the Start button. The service status should now display "Started".
5. To return to the list of services, click the OK, and exit the MMC Console.

You can also enable NetTcpBinding in configuration like this.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding name="portSharingBinding" 
                   portSharingEnabled="true" />
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/MyService"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  contract="IMyService"
                  bindingConfiguration="portSharingBinding" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

If port sharing service is enabled and you manually started it,check if another application is running on the port 8523. You can use Netstat -a in command prompt or TCPView from the following address.
[TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)

Comment: My net.tcp port sharing service is running already. Also I tried adding portSharingEnabled attribute to the config file. After that I get AddressAlreadyInUseException. I have tried TCPView and netstat commands to find all active ports but the port I am using (8523) is not listed there. I can see this port listed only when I try to debug this service as I mentioned earlier when studio starts WcfSvcHost.exe.

Comment: The last thing besides these is the firewall.Can you post your config file in the original post?

Comment: Added config to original post. Thanks.

Comment: Using Visual Studio command prompt to install your Service, you should also use SvcUtil to generate your Service Proxy file and then you should reference them in your solution.Have you done this?

Comment: I tried using SvcUtil to generate App.config but it gave me same exception that "target machine actively refused it.." . I believe, VS studio will do the same when we try to add the service reference using this endpoint. Also I have uninstalled all antivirus and disabled all firewalls. No luck.

Comment: I think you're right on that. I replicated your issue. No luck to solve it yet.

Comment: Turns out net.Tcp Listener adapter service must be started as well as net.tcp port sharing.

Comment: Its already turned On. Does it work for you after starting that service? It does not work for me though...

Comment: Yes. That's the issue I think we have.

Comment: The issue was a silly mistake here. My apologies. I was not able to post my service class code because stack overflow did not allow me. 

In myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWCFService)),  I mistakenly referenced the windows service class instead of WCF service. That is the reason it was not creating WCF service host. Aria, I appreciate your help. Thanks.